# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL Couldn't load from 'http://88.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm having trouble calling a web service from php.
With my personnal website, nothing wrong. But when i try from my dedicated server :

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://88.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/SongBoxServeur/GestionSongBox?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://88.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/SongBoxServeur/GestionSongBox?wsdl"

The same .php on my website and dedicated server :

```
 function __construct( $_ip, $_num_serie) {
 $this->ip = $_ip;
$this->num_serie = $_num_serie;
$this->soap = new SoapClient("http://".$this->ip.":8080/SongBoxServeur/GestionSongBox?wsdl",array(
                                    'trace' => true,
                                    'exceptions' => true));
                                    }
```

What could the problem be? (soap is enabled on both) Thx in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find my problem : php.ini.

```
 default_socket_timeout = 0
```

change by:

```
default_socket_timeout =300
```

And now, it's works !!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `$this->ip` is accessible from the server. In other words, from the dedicated server, make sure you can open up http://88.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/SongBoxServeur/GestionSongBox?wsdl in a browser. If you can't, there's some networking configuration you need to attend to first.

Comment: I try command : lynx http://88.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/SongBoxServeur/GestionSongBox?wsdl and i can access !

Comment: Hmm, ok. Is `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your php.ini? You can check with phpinfo().

Comment: allow_url_fopen On
and soap :
Soap Client enabled
Soap Server enabled

Comment: Ok, good. Make sure that you can download the file from PHP with `file_get_contents()`. In other words, run `file_get_contents("http://".$this->ip.":8080/SongBoxServeur/GestionSongBox?wsdl")` and make sure you get the WSDL back.

Comment: I have the following error :
Warning: file_get_contents(http://88.X.X.X:8080/SongBoxServeur/GestionSongBox?wsdlâ€Œâ€‹): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /var/www/path/include/songbox.php on line 10

but same with http://www.google.fr/

Comment: Sry, with google :
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/LifeSong/include/songbox.php on line 10



Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.frâ€Œâ€‹): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/path/include/songbox.php on line 10



But same error on my personnal website

Comment: There's some garbage characters in the code you're pasting, so I'm not sure what URLs you're trying to load. "Name or service not known" usually means that DNS lookups don't work on the server. Can you ping www.google.fr? How about this? `file_get_contents("http://www.google.fr/")`

Comment: Following error with `file_get_contents("http://www.google.fr/")`  : `Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.fr/): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /var/www/path/include/songbox.php on line 10`
Ping on my dedicated server : `root@ks310812:~# ping http://www.google.fr/
ping: unknown host http://www.google.fr/
root@ks310812:~# ping google.fr
PING google.fr (173.194.40.127) 56(84) bytes of data.` works with google.fr but not with `http://www.google.fr/`

Comment: That's to be expected. Ping expects the hostname or IP, not the protocol (http://). I'm not sure what the issue is on your server, but it appears there's something blocking you from downloading external URLs from PHP. Perhaps there's some PHP setting that is blocking it or maybe a security precaution (mod_security perhaps?). It can be a million different things. You'll need to ask your hosting provider or server admin.

Comment: Ok, i will do it tomorrow ! Thx for your help !